# Google sign in button with automatic approval of authorizations

Tags: javascript, google-signin, google-oauth

I've seen many threads about it but cannot find a satisfying answer: when using the Google sign-in button (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in), is it possible to already have the authorizations accepted ? Like if I add the client ID of my app somewhere in the Google console ?

For now I'm calling the auth2.grantOfflineAccess when clicking the button (so I can pass the returned `code` to my backend and make sure the user is from the expected domain).

If you're able to answer the first question and - bonus point - know if what I'm doing after clicking the button is right, you'd be awesome !

Comment: You want to have users automatically accept authorisations required by your application?

Comment: Yes, because they're all from the same domain (that's GSuite, not basic gmail accounts) and so the admin of this domain would like to accept the authorizations for them, automatically.

Comment: Okay - in that case no, you can't do it for very obvious reasons.

Comment: Yes, I think what you are looking for is described here: https://developers.google.com/identity/work/it-apps ... it explains how to do the domain check and whitelist your app client ID to avoid the consent confirmation screen. Let me know if that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Steven's comment, I'm now able to have the authorizations accepted by default. Be aware there will still be a second popup (after the one that requests your email and password) to inform you that your admin has granted the app to access your data. Only at your first connection though.

So what you need to do is to follow the third step of [this document](https://developers.google.com/identity/work/it-apps). They say you only need the `plus.me` and `userinfo.email` scopes if you only request the basic profile of the user but it was not working in my case, I also needed the `userinfo.profile` scope (because I use `grantOfflineAccess()` ?).